# Right capacitance for a capacitor parallel over power output?

Tags: power, capacitor, current, solenoid, 74hc595

I am building a self playing piano. I daisy-chained 11 74hc595 shift registers to control (11*8) solenoids. (figure 1 only shows 1). The solenoids are rated at 2 Amps each.
I use SPI from the arduino to bit bang data to get PWM over the outputs at about 20 kHz to make the keys play harder and softer. But only for about half a second until the key is pressed, then is sets it to 255/255.
But even when I power a solenoid directly at 255/255 it is only capable of pressing the piano key 1 out of about 5 times. I think it doesn't always get the power it needs.

I thought it would be a good idea to add a parallel capacitor (C1) close to every group of 8 solenoids. But what would be a good capacitance?

[EDIT] I don't have a o'scope. I am using IRFZ44N Transistor N-Channel Rectifier Power Mosfets. 8 mosfets are grouped togheter (total 11 groups), the wires from my PSU to these groups are 18 AWG and ranging from 30 to 100 cm in length.

[EDIT 2] I added a gnd wire in the schematic between logic and solenoid side. I added 3 photos, pls dont judge the solder quality, its from 3 years ago. I also still need to do some wire management and actually fix the boards onto something because now they are just hanging there.
I am currently testing with 47 uF, 220 uF, 470uF and 1000 uF. But dont see any difference so far. I also have a old (but still usable) car battery, would that be a better power supply?

[image: 1 shift register setup]

[image: bottom side of one of the 11 boards]

[image: up side of one of the 11 boards]
[image: 11 boards for 88 solenoids overview]

Comment: It sounds like you don't have an oscilloscope available to test your theory of it not always getting the power it needs. In which case, why not add the 1 mF capacitor you have illustrated and try it, then try with two, etc.

Comment: simple test: if you just pull the FET gate high by touching the wire to +12V, do you get enough drive?

Comment: I will take a guess but it appears you are not getting enough power from the power supply, it is probably folding back leaving enough for the Arduino but not the solenoid. Consider if you activate more then one key. If you want to go the capacitor route you will need several thousand Uf, 2A is a lot of current. What size is your wire and how long is it?

Comment: What MOSFETs are you using, and are you sure you are driving the gates hard enough?

Comment: you might want to use several caps in parrelel so that ESR is divided and they can respond N times faster than a single large cap.

Comment: The specific routing of the ground wire is important, to avoid interference between the solenoids and logic circuit. But your circuit shows no connection at all between the logic ground and solenoid driver ground. Please correct the circuit, and show us a photo of the setup including all wiring.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, Yes you are right, I forgot it in the schematic but it is on the boards. See the post edits.

Comment: @Gil, See the post edits

Comment: @danmcb yes i get enough drive

Comment: @evildemonic  I am using IRFZ44N Transistor N-Channel Rectifier Power Mosfets

Comment: Redo the soldering. You don't need a 2 amp solenoid to pull a small piece of wood. Consider using lower current solenoids.

Comment: The on resistance of those MOSFETs may be a bit too high with only 5 V gate drive.  If you could drive the gates with 12 V that would be much better.  They are not advertised as "logic level".

Comment: @tim I did consider that and tested a few before I build all this but they are either way too expensive or not strong enough. These are TAU-0826B 12V 20N 10MM which I got for a pretty good deal.